Why isn't my data in the viewmodel saving? Jetpack Compose + Firebase
I am trying to do an auth system and I am encountering a problem. My data in the view model is not saving even tho I am using the same viewmodel entity. My signUpResponse and signInResponse doesn't modify in the viewmodel and not on the screen and I don't understand why...
This is my implementation
override suspend fun signUpAccount(email: String, password: String): Resource<Boolean>
    =try {
        val result = mutableStateOf(false)
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).await()

        if(auth.currentUser != null)
            result.value = true

        Log.d("fbAuth","signUp: ${result.value}")
        Resource.Success(result.value)
    }catch(ex: Exception){
        Resource.Failure(ex)
    }

    override suspend fun signInAccount(email: String, password: String): Resource<Boolean>
    =try{
        val result = mutableStateOf(false)
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).await()

        if(auth.currentUser != null)
            result.value = true

        Log.d("fbAuth","signIn: ${result.value}")
        Resource.Success(result.value)
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        Resource.Failure(ex)
    }

This is in my ViewModel
private var _signUpResponse = mutableStateOf<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Success(false))
    val signUpResponse: MutableState<Resource<Boolean>> = _signUpResponse

    private val _signInResponse = mutableStateOf<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Success(false))
    val signInResponse: MutableState<Resource<Boolean>> = _signInResponse

    fun signUpUser(email: String,password: String)
            =viewModelScope.launch {
        _signUpResponse.value = Resource.Loading
        _signUpResponse.value = authRepository.signUpAccount(email, password)
        Log.d("fbAuthSignUp",_signUpResponse.value.toString())
    }

    fun signInUser(email: String,password: String)
            =viewModelScope.launch {
        _signInResponse.value = Resource.Loading
        _signInResponse.value = authRepository.signInAccount(email, password)
        Log.d("fbAuthLogin",_signInResponse.value.toString())
    }

This is what I tried in the screen kotlin file
authViewModel.signUpUser(email,password)
    when(val signUpResponse = authViewModel.signUpResponse.value){
        is Resource.Loading -> ProgressBar(context)

        is Resource.Success ->signUpResponse.apply{
            Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", "Success#1 ${authViewModel.signUpResponse.value}")
            if(result)
            {
                signUpResult = true
                Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", "sign up account check")
            }
        }

        is Resource.Failure -> signUpResponse.apply {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    Log.d("fbAuthSignUp",signUpResult.toString())
    if(signUpResult){
        Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", authViewModel.createAccountResponse.value.toString())
        authViewModel.createAccount(name, email, password)
        when(val createAccountResponse = authViewModel.createAccountResponse.value){
            is Resource.Loading -> ProgressBar(context)

            is Resource.Success -> createAccountResponse.apply{
                Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", "Success#2")
                if(result)
                {
                    createAccountResult = true
                    Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", "createAccount check")
                }

            }

            is Resource.Failure -> createAccountResponse.apply {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }

    Log.d("fbAuthSignUp", signUpResult.toString() + createAccountResult.toString())
    if(signUpResult && createAccountResult){
        Log.d("mainGoal","verified sign up")
        navController.navigate("MainGoalScreen")
    }
}


What do you get printed out at this line Log.d("fbAuth","signUp: ${result.value}")?
